# Python excute shell cmd but get nothing output when set daemon

Tags: python, stdout, freebsd, python-daemon

- OS Environment: Pfsense 2.4.4 based on FreeBSD 11.2-RELEASE-p10
- Python: Python 2.7.16 (default, May 10 2019, 17:54:37)
- Problem description:

I want to set my first python script running as a daemon, and I define a function:

```
def set_daemon(cur_woring_path):
    try:
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid > 0:
            sys.exit(0)
    except OSError, e:
        print "First fork failed:%s" % e.message
        sys.exit(1)

    os.chdir(cur_woring_path)
    os.setsid()
    os.umask(0)

    try:
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid > 0:
            sys.exit(0)
    except OSError, e:
        print "Second fork failed:%s" % e.message
        sys.exit(1)

    os.close(sys.stdin.fileno())
    os.close(sys.stdout.fileno())
    os.close(sys.stderr.fileno())
```

After I called `set_daemon(...)`, I wan to execute shell command and get the output:

```
    load_logger_config("INFO")
    logger = logging.getLogger("debug_info_logger")

    target_process_name = "my_second_process.py"
    set_daemon("/root")

    cmd = "ps -aux | grep " + target_process_name + "| grep -v grep|awk -F \" \" '{print $2}' "
    out = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
    logger.warning("Found process is running..., pid = %s", out.stdout.read()[:-1])
```

But the `out` string is always empty, I have tried:

```
commands.getoutput(cmd)
os.popen(cmd)
popen2

redirect to file is empty too.
cmd = "ps -aux | grep " + target_process_name + "| grep -v grep|awk -F \" \" '{print $2}' > tmp.txt"

...
```

Cause of the problem maybe:

```
    os.close(sys.stdin.fileno())
    os.close(sys.stdout.fileno())
    os.close(sys.stderr.fileno())
```

because without `set_daemon`, everything is ok.
I've searched google, but nothing help.

Are there any solutions? I need both `set_daemon` and `shell output`, could I reopen the stdout fileno? I appreciate a lot anyone could help me

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: Is this a problem only about python2, or just my coding mistake. I am really confused. thanks anyway!

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer. I think this should work pretty much identically (or not work) on Python 3 actually. I'm looking at the `subprocess.Popen()` mess as probably the culprit but not in a place where I can troubleshoot properly.

Comment: You should break your command into the individual pieces as a list of strings.

Comment: @James That alone will not help, it requires `shell=True` or a significant refactoring as it is now.

Comment: Running just `ps -aux` in a subprocess and replacing the pipeline with Python-native code should be just 3-4 lines and give you much more control over the process. My guess is that the Python script's name is not visible in the `ps` listing but that's just a vague conjecture. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess

Comment: I  just  delete  the flowing  3  line  to  avoid  this  problem  temporarily       
`os.close(sys.stdin.fileno())`  
` os.close(sys.stdout.fileno())`  
`os.close(sys.stderr.fileno())`  
and then, I can get `ps -aux` output smoothly, but sometimes the python script output will appear on the terminal. This may not be the best solution. I will keep trying, thanks everyone! If anybody finds a better way, I will appreciate it if you could tell me.